# Problems with sound in Java and USB sound card

Tags: java, audio, usb, alsa

I've been using Java for a college software development class, and recently we have been doing some work with building an MP3 player.

My problem is that the sound in Java does not play correctly. I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 and I have a laptop, but i'm using an external sound card (USB, because my built in sound doesn't sound very good). Problem is that Java always plays sound though my laptops internal soundcard (even though Ubuntu lists the internal sound as being off), so I hear sound from my little laptop speakers and not the speakers hooked up to my soundcard.

I can get it to play though the soundcard by using the aoss program but its a pain to do this. I'm using alsa on my system with a USB soundcard, it works fine with other sound programs and music players, any ideas on how to fix this problem? I'm happy to provide any information that anyone needs or would find helpful. Thanks!

Comment: How does your Java code reach the sound card?

Comment: I haven't written in code for java to reach the sound card, I assumed java used the system defaults.  How would I go about telling java to reach the soundcard?

Comment: how do you currently play sounds?

Comment: I've been using this test file, http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SimpleAudioPlayer.java.html and this file causes the problem described before when I play a file.  File plays, but it is out of my laptop internal sound not my soundcard.

Comment: Ok, if it helps anyone to figure the problem out, I can get sound correctly (without any setup or anything) if I use OpenJDK java 6 runtime instead of sun java.  Any idea why there is a difference, some type of configuration setting or something?

Comment: K guys, I think the problem is something with how my computer or soundcard is setup (not something with my code).  So if you guys have ideas feel free to post, but I posted my problems in the ubuntu forms, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat:  I am not familiar with JavaSound.

Based on the provided example code, it looks like the

```
DataLine.Info   info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
```

line is the one that requests the playback mechanism, and that the audioformat you provide matches the built-in sound card.

You need to find out what mechanisms are available to you for selecting a given one explicitly, instead of just the first one which is "good enough".

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but isn't the audioFormat gotten from the soundfile i'm reading?  I'm pretty sure that just gives us info about the file's setup.  I think the problem might have to do with java using the wrong mixer, but i'm not sure.  You know anything about that?